# Is readfile() failing or is this something only Chrome is getting right?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've been having an issue with a streamed file download from my site but I'm still unable to work out how it is failing.

The site is outputting a large XML file (180MB) using PHP's readfile(). We're using Zend Framework for the controller but are disabling the view renderer so the file should be being output correctly.

If the file is downloaded in Chrome, the download completes and the file is intact. However, if the file is downloaded in Firefox, IE or even via wget, the download is interrupted at ~178MB (All at the same point as far as I can tell). I can see the ".part" file from Firefox and where it's being interrupted doesn't look like it should be a major issue (the next character would be a '>').

We've checked the file on the server. We don't put the closing '?>' on our PHP scripts to avoid any end of file whitespace issues so it shouldn't be that.

Not sure what's going on or where next to look.

Comment: Do you send and receive the `Content-Length` header? It's essential.

Comment: Yes and they match the filesize on the server.

Comment: Can you feed a small(er) data sample into your XML process? Then we can make some better guesses if it is size or format related

Comment: I have now tried a smaller file and it still fails at 99% in wget and Firefox but completes in Chrome. I did notice that Chrome seems to wait for a bit at 99% before completing whereas the failures seem to happen instantly at 99%.